# Omni Flow not storing Skill Requirements Collection Variable

Tags: visual-workflow, servicecloud, omnichannel

I'm trying to use Skill-Based Routing to route Chats in my Org. It seems my options to do this are to 1) use a Visualforce Pre chat form page that stores Chat Transcript record information that then routes the Chat via a Skill-Based Routing Rule mapping set, 2) use a Custom LWC that pretty much does that as well, 3) or build an Omni Flow using the template and configure my own skill-based routing setup.

I've opted for the third option, as I am not familiar enough with Visualforce or LWC to build something out. I've configured everything to a point that it functions up to when Skills are being assigned based on Pre chat form input. Every point in the Flow that stores a Skill to the Skill Requirements Collection variable successfully stores a value according to debugging.

However, for whatever reason, the next time the collection variable is referenced, I can see in the debugger that it is once again null. This can happen multiple times within the Flow where if I add one skill (step 1), then add another skill afterward (step 2), then route the work item afterward (step 3). The Skill Requirements variable will be updated during step 1, then becomes null again immediately after step 1, then get updated during step 2, then is null immediately afterwards once again. As a result, step 3 is performed using an empty Skill Collection variable, so no skills are used for routing.

Has anyone ever run into a similar issue like this before? Any suggestions on how I can get this to work? Ideally, I'd like to dynamically assign skills to Chats based on multiple fields within the Pre chat form with the use of an Omni Flow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's been a little moment since you posted but the solution to this is to add your skillrequirements collection to the aggregated skills requirement section.

[image: Flow visual]